# min-width not working and words break to adjust width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In the below image the options break and come to the next line to adjust the width.
[image: Open image here]

This is the CSS code for this div

```
.single_topic {
  margin-right: 12px;
  padding: 8px 18px 9px 18px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have tried display: inline but it doesn't work. How to fix this?

Comment: [white-space: nowrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) might help you out. In case it doesn't help, please create [mcve]

Comment: white-space: nowrap; is working but when the div is set min-width: 100px; the div doesn't increase its width with content.

Comment: @AnkurSingh Then please do provide a [mcve].